# JWPlayer7 not loading the skin colors

Tags: angularjs, jwplayer, jwplayer7

I have a weird error with jwplayer.

I configure it from a Angular JS Controller and load it with a simple preview button which loads the `jwplayer` with the requested conf.

As simple as this.

```
jwplayer(id).setup(config);
```

I have a skin and the skin colors (active, inactive, background) configured.

The issue happens when I click the preview button. Sometimes the player loads with the correct colors and sometimes the player loads with the default skin colors.

Every other `jwplayer` property get loaded correctly. If I change the skin model it will always load that model but will have the same issue with the colors.

I ran a `jwplayer(attribute_id).getConfig()` to check which conf has been loaded in both cases and they are exactly the same.

So how is it possible the `jwplayer` has the skin colors loaded but they don't work in some cases?

Skin related conf obtained from the js api:

```
skin: "seven"
skinColorActive: "#FFFFFF"
skinColorBackground: "#3B0239"
skinColorInactive: "#EE2A7B"
skinUrl: undefined
```

The player's version I am using is the 7.4.3

**UPDATE**

I figured out the issue. I have a function to random generate (number and characters) `jwplayer id`'s in case I have a couple of jwplayers in the same page they have different ids.

Every time I generated a new `jwplayer` it would use a different id. So I noticed the colors weren't working when the `jwplayer id` was starting with a number.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

So for some reason although the JQuery selector was wrong, just the colors weren't working, the rest of the setup was working fine.

I assume the CSS couldn't work with a wrong id selector and that's why the colors wouldn't show up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I have a function to random generate (number and characters) jwplayer ids in case I have a couple of jwplayers in the same page they have different ids.

Every time I generated a new jwplayer it would use a different id. So I noticed the colors werent working when the jwplayer id was starting with a number.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

So for some reason although the JQuery selector was wrong, just the colors werent working, the rest of the setup was working fine.

I assume the CSS couldnt work with a wrong id selector and that's why the colors wouldnt show up...

Answer (score 1):

Skin changes are implemented in your CSS file or within `<style></style>` tags in the header. It looks like your config file is attempting to pull them into the JavaScript player setup. Here are guidelines for designing and implementing your own skin: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/css-skinning/skins_creating/

Additionally, I would ensure that you're referencing the correct playback states (idle, buffering, playing, paused) as defined in the JavaScript API when you call for the skin change: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/api/javascript_api_reference/#playback

Comment: Thanks, I updated my response, it was related to the jquery selector.